# how to join tables in a new table in SQLite in C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have created two tables in an SQLite database and want to join them together into a new table, so I can use that to display information. 
What I have until now is this:

```
string cmd        = string.Format( "select * from {0} join {1}", table1, table2 );
_sqlCommand.CommandText = cmd;
_sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery( );
```

But that doesn't create a new table does it?
How can I now access the information that has been joined?

Comment: join doesn't create new table. it's only a projection of the results of the two tables.

Comment: @JW. So, how can I access the information conatined in that projection?

Comment: remember that you are executing a `SELECT` statement so you would use `DataAdapter` or `DataReader` to fetch the result, here's an good tutorial, [Using DataReader](http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-oledbcommand-executereader.htm) and [Using DataAdapter](http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-oledbdataadapter.htm)